# print stack trace of application crash in vxworks

Tags: vxworks

I'm new to vxworks and working on a c++ based embedded project using vxworks(PowerPC processor). The problem I'm facing is my application is getting crashed sometimes(rarely) and I'm not able to identify the location of the crash since nothing is getting printed on the tera terminal(loading the executable from host machine using `ld<App.out` command from tera term console application). I'm not getting useful resources in the internet about debugging in vxworks. Can somebody suggest ways of identifying the trace of where crash has occurred in vxworks.

Answer (score 2):

Two commands useful for debugging are `i` and `tt`.

`i` simply prints out the list of tasks with their names and states. It can be used to find which task(s) failed.

`tt` displays stack trace for a task.
Example from the manual:

```
-> tt "logTask"
     3ab92 _vxTaskEntry   +10 : _logTask (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
      ee6e _logTask       +12 : _read (5, 3f8a10, 20)
      d460 _read          +10 : _iosRead (5, 3f8a10, 20)
      e234 _iosRead       +9c : _pipeRead (3fce1c, 3f8a10, 20)
     23978 _pipeRead      +24 : _semTake (3f8b78)
    value = 0 = 0x0
```

Further information on `tt` is available at [dbgLib](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/%7Ecourses/ee8205/Data-Sheets/Tornado-VxWorks/vxworks/ref/dbgLib.html#tt). `i` command is described at `usrLib`, however I can not find its manual online. Its source is available at [here](http://en.verysource.com/code/2494032_1/usrLib.c.html), where it is listed as:

> - i         [task]           Summary of tasks' TCBs

Comment: when the application gets crashed I think there is no way to check the status of tasks, since it is no longer possible to make another remote connection(via tera term console from host machine) to the same processor core where my application ran to check the tasks status. I have to hard restart my vxworks board.

Answer (score 0):

One important item to do: Make sure that any task running C++ code has been created with the option VX_FP_TASK.
That could explain the "crash" in rare case.

Comment: Can you tell how to specify this option. Is there a way in Workbench IDE?

Comment: Yes this is possible when you start the task from the IDE (Run/Debug task) you can set the option. Even while debugging you can update the task option for any running task in the system!